# Single word for "this is why"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Consider:

Where = here

When = now

What = this

How = thus

Why = (this is why)??

With the above, you could answer a question with the word on the left with just the single word on the right as an answer without additional information when the context is implicit, or can be provided with non-verbal cues such as pointing or demonstrating.

Is there a single word answer to the question "why?" to describe **this reason** or **this is why** when the context is implicit? Both **therefore** and **because** are inadequate as they require additional information.

Comment: How I have most often heard why questions answered with a single word is: ***because***, without additional information.

Comment: @GMB Does it really answer a question?

Comment: No, it doesn't - but neither does "thus" answer "how?" Your "when" and "where" examples offer a single-word *value* that answers the question. All of the others require additional information. If you have a single-word reason, then it will answer "why?"

Comment: @bye Turn your above comment into an answer. It is the answer to this question, and even points out the error in the question itself.

Comment: What bye said. To put it another way, what makes "here" the answer to "where"? Why isn't it "there"? Or "on the moon"? *All* of these questions may need more information. Sometimes, that "more information" can be encapsulated in a single word (e.g. "here"), but sometimes, it can't be (e.g. "on the moon").

Comment: @Marthaª "here" is totally different to "there" because it points to the current context, and is complete without additional information, whereas "there" isn't complete. The same goes for now and any time which is "not-now". The answers I gave are equivalent to saying "as it is in the current context" just with a different word for the dimension (time, location, manner or reason) we're talking about. In fact a language doesn't need separate words for each, the dimension (e.g reason) could be inferred from the question alone.

Comment: I fail to see how "here" is any more complete an answer than "there" (or "on the moon" or "on the little shelf behind my ear" as my mother is fond of putting it).

Comment: Ok, different slant: imagine that we replaced the words "here" "now" "thus" and so on with "this" in the English language. We'd understand that "this" means "now" if the question contains "when", and means "here" if the question contains "where". "this" could then be used to answer "how" and "why" type questions if the manner or reason is obvious from the context, which I admit is more difficult that time or location (though "here" isn't always clear either: you could say that on the phone without the other person knowing where you are).

Comment: In many contexts "here" is a complete answer, if the person asking the question knows where you are standing, whereas "there" can never be complete. There's only one "here" and an infinite amount of "there"s, and so long as "here" is known to the person asking, it's a complete answer.

Comment: I wonder if behind this question somewhere there's a parent or teacher with a habit of insisting that "because" is not a complete sentence (or some such attempt at disguising as grammar a problem that is actually behavioral). The fact remains that "here" is no more (or less) complete an answer than "because"; any difference between them is physical, not linguistic.

Comment: @JPmiaou "here" is a complete answer if the person knows where you are. Whether "because" is a complete really depends on it's accepted usage. I'd be inclined to say that "because" always requires follow-up, unless you're specifically pointing out that you don't want to provide a reason. Else you would say "because of X..." or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seldom used alternative to because and therefore, is [*wherefore*](http://gog.is/define+wherefore).

If you want good examples, read the works of Shakespeare.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that this is the best fit (it has nothing to do with our current use of "where", see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wherefore ). Even though it is equivalent to "therefore", "therefore" as @Bye pointed out is used mostly used in an "it follows that" manner, whereas "wherefore" could be used as a single word if the reason is clear from current action or context.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, *because* is very often used.

Yes, it requires more information, but so does *thus*! If I ask how you did something and you answer me: "thus," I will know as much as when I ask you why and you tell me: "because."

Another word you could use is *hence*, meaning *as a consequence*, *for this reason*. It is used in the inverse way of because:

> We bought ice cream because it was warm and we needed to cool down.
>   It was warm and we needed to cool down; hence, we bought ice cream.

It may appear a bit archaic or formal though. Personally I would prefer it as the one-word reply to *why*, rather than *because*. But I am weird in that.

Comment: I like "hence", though it suffers the same association to "it follows that" as therefore does (as highlighted by @bye). I suppose "because" suffers from association with the childish use of not providing a reason...

Answer (score 2):

How I have most often heard why questions answered with a single word is: ***because***, without additional information. It may not answer a question in terms of an explanation, but if only one word is to be used, a more commonly used one may not be available. And, common use is at least some of the time based on collective common sense. Especially for why questions that aren't strictly answerable in the first place, *because* is a response to the question, even if it does prompt a further inquiry.

Answer (score -1):

"Why" is asking about the reason of something happened . so , if you want to show the reason of this "something" you can't reply with only one word . i mean you must explain it .
 and if you don't want to show the reason i think "causeless" fits your needs .

Answer (score -2):

I think that you can't answer such a question with a single word. It requires *additional information*, an explanation.

> ­If not, does anyone know if other languages perhaps do have a single word for this?

Not me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that logic would also apply to a "how" question which you could answer with "thus". "thus" when used as a single word needs to be accompanied by some additional information, typically non-verbal.

Comment: @AndyHasIt - you can also say "because" and point. There is an archaic use of *therefore* (which answers *wherefore*), but *therefore* has semantically drifted to meaning something more like "it follows that" (*sequitur*) than the original "because".

Comment: @bye or you can say "Because" and *not* point. Parents of three-year-olds are driven to this shift daily.

Comment: Of course you can answer a question that way. If the answer isn't is a good one is not necessary.